# IDE for C, windows

Tags: windows, c, ide

I would like to try a good ide for C. Please list your favorite ide for C not the one that is considered the best.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: We don't answer "what's your favorite ..." here. Instead, you give the requirements you have for the software and we try to find a suitable tool. "Good" or "the best" do not qualify as requirements. Requirements should be measurable. E.g. say: "price is less than 200 €", "must compile for MSP430" and "has built-in support fro Git"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using [NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html), but you can use:

## FREE

- [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) with the [C/C++ Package](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/sr2/eclipse-ide-cc-developers)
- [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads)
- [CodeLite](https://codelite.org/)
- [KDevelop](https://www.kdevelop.org/download)
- [Geany](https://www.geany.org/download/releases/)

## PAID

- [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/download/#section=windows)
- [AppCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/download/) Has C/C++ support but it is for iOS Applications not for desktop

Comment: Since it´s for Windows Visual Studio must be mentioned, even I personaly dislike it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the paid list: [LabWindows/CVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LabWindows/CVI)

Comment: I think this is specific to National Instruments data acquisition environment and not for general purpose programming.

Comment: It is a general purpose C compiler (based on Clang), but adds a lot of libraries. I used to use it a lot for general purpose C and I still teach it in industrial settings (full disclosure).